# Undefined array key "merge_same_household"

Tags: wordpress, error, php, templates, custom-templates

I'm trying to **export contacts** from the list in CiviCRM but got a visual warning which does not let me proceed:

> Warning: Undefined array key "merge_same_household" in /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/es_MX/%%00/00A/00AEAD8F%%Select.tpl.php on line 86
>
> Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/es_MX/%%00/00A/00AEAD8F%%Select.tpl.php on line 86

I've navigated to the path and opened the file ***"00AEAD8F%%Select.tpl.php"*** on line **86**.

```
  <div class="content crm-content-mergeSameHousehold">
    &nbsp;<?php echo $this->_tpl_vars['form']['merge_same_household']['html']; ?>
  </div>
```

I'm not sure what the problem is. I was thinking about **replacing the file** with a new one downloaded from the repository **or** even **deleting** it although I'm not sure.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What happens when you click Continuar? Those are warnings and not errors, so in theory you should be able to continue. Is it possible that the PHP error_reporting level is set on your server?
Nothing wrong with that file.

Comment: @LarsSG If I click "continue" everything works as normal, however this "warning" was not showing up before and it's kind of intriguing to see this. My server is a Virtual Machine with a Bitnami WordPress stack.

Comment: It's just PHP saying that it's trying to look up something that is empty and giving a warning because it is empty (which is more like maybe something isn't working as expected rather than a real error). In this case it is that PHP versions have changed over time and what once was OK now generates a warning.

Comment: I would check in php.ini and see if perhaps your error_reporting setting has changed. Also check WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY in wp-config and error_reporting in civicrm.settings.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning will be [fixed in future versions](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/26467). In the meantime, changing the error_reporting level should remove it.

Comment: Sorry but I understand this, but how can I error_reporting level in the CiviCRM installation in WordPress if I don't already have the line 'define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );' in the wp-config.php file?