# Undefined array key "email_greeting_display"

Tags: wordpress, php, message-templates, civicrm.settings.php, php7

I'm trying to visualize a *contact (organization)* and I'm receiving the following warning in the *"Communication preferences"* section.

> Warning: Undefined array key "email_greeting_display" in /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/es_MX/%%77/77A/77AF58B9%%CommunicationPreferences.tpl.php on line 53

However, this does not influence when updating the data and does not cause me major problems.

[image]

I've completely removed any trace of `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in the **wp-config.php** file

Answer (score 0):

This is the same problem as [your previous question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/45057/undefined-array-key-merge-same-household/). Did you also check php.ini? Bitnami has instructions on their site to find php.ini and edit it. If you can figure out where the problem is, maybe we could let Bitnami know, because it seems like a configuration problem on their end, unless you've changed it.